# Slow internet on ubuntu 23.10

Tags: internet, 23.10

I'm on version 23.10 of Ubuntu, and the speed offered by my internet company is 500Mbps. But only on Ubuntu, I can't go above 98Mbps.

The network card: Gigabit LAN Realtek® RTL8111H

I'm new to the system. I have already tried updating the drivers and nothing changed.

Comment: Did you check the internet speed with other devices or OS and show any difference??

Comment: Yes, using Windows I can get up to 650mbps. but when I go to Ubuntu it doesn't exceed 98mbps